# Using barcode or qcode with Jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports, barcode

I have a project developed using JSF and PrimeFaces. I need to display barcode on PDF with Jasper. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: what is the effort from your end?

Comment: asking for suggestion on SO ; )

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [barcode4j](http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/) to generate the barcode (note IReport can already handle these but I will show you the java way).

Make a metod that returns the barcode (Image) es.

```
public static synchronized Image getGS1_128Production(String codeProduzione) {

    if (codeProduzione==null){
        return null;
    }
    GS1_128 g = new GS1_128(codeProduzione);
    //Start personalizzing barcode
    int dpi = 150;
    if (code.length()>40){
        dpi = 100;
    }
    if (code.length()>57){
        dpi = 75;
    }

    c.doQuietZone(true);
    c.setQuietZone(5);
    c.setFontSize(2d);

    boolean antiAlias = false;
    int orientation = 0;

    BitmapCanvasProvider canvas = new BitmapCanvasProvider(dpi, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY, antiAlias, orientation);
    c.generateBarcode(canvas, code);

    return canvas.getBufferedImage();
}
```

Then in your jrxml

```
<image scaleImage="Clip" hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle" isUsingCache="false" onErrorType="Blank">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="65" y="66" width="405" height="82">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{GS1_128}!=null)]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <imageExpression class="java.awt.Image"><![CDATA[jdd.trace.barcode.BarCode4J.getGS1_128Production($F{GS1_128})]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

Note: in my example the static metodo `getGS1_128Production` is within my class 
`BarCode4J` that is in the package `jdd.trace.barcode`

Furthermore, you can naturally use non static metods by for example passing the barcode Image as a parameter or passing your object as a parameter into the jrxml.

These image are printable and readable (tested with barcode readers), but if you like high resolution images I suggest you use the SVG instead of Image